# How to make logos visually equal?

Tags: logo, resize

I have a board with various logos. I want to make them equal. So I set the equal height, e.g. 10cm.

However, this is not quite right, as logos that are long (e.g. "nice-company"), they visually dominate over logos that are more square (e.g. "box").

Do you have any smart suggestion how to make them visually equals?

Comment: These are known as "Logo Graveyards". Don't spend much time on it. Nobody cares about them.

Comment: I'm certain there is a good duplicate for this but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is google for some examples and see what others are doing. Logos will rarely work well together, but to get the best results you should imagine a grid and each logo should somehow be centered in its own box, like in this image below.

Obviously some fonts will look larger than others, but this is probably the best you can do and people are used to "reading" these logo walls.

[image]